# Я хотел попробовать Гиперболический танген и уменя вышла ошибка TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python

```
x1=np.dot(X,syn0)
l1=math.tanh(x1)
x2=np.dot(l1,syn1)
l2=math.tanh(x2)
x3=np.dot(l2,syn2)
l3=math.tanh(x3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну так причина ошибки написана в явном виде "only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars". Причем в той части выдачи интерпретатора, которую вы нам почему-то не показали -  еще и сказано в какой строке вашей программы это произошло.

Я могу только предположить, что это имело место в строке l1=math.tanh(x1), где x1 numpy-массив, а функция tanh  модуля math работает только с одним числом (или в вектором с единственным элементом).

Попробуйте использовать функцию tanh  из numpy.

```
 l1=np.tanh(x1)
```